# How to import localhost.sql into global space of phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost

I wanted to upgrade xampp, so i backed up htdocs and exported whole database (localhost.sql). After that i uninstalled old xampp. I installed new xampp and trying to import that localhost.sql file but because of large file it showed error. So i raised the limit of maximum volumn( in my.ini using `myisam_sort_buffer_size = 68M`).

Now i am trying to import that localhost.sql file to the phpmyadmin, using command line . `mysql -u root -p < localhost.sql`. But it is asking a database name, but localhost.sql contains multiple databases which are in the global space of phpmyadmin. What to do?

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a web-based interface that you can use to manage a MySQL or MariaDB database installation. Whatever you're doing on the command line is not related to phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

Export: mysqldump -uuser -ppassword db > file.sql - move to server, then Import: mysql -uuser -ppassword db > file.sql. Repeat for each database. Note that the tables are from